# multithreading - pause thread when condition satisifes in another class and start new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

This question is similar to the one asked here:
[Pausing Thread and resuming](http://[enter%20link%20description%20here][1]).

I have 5 classes :
Class A , B , C , D , E.

Class A is the main class which starts the threads that start Class B.
Class B starts Class C which in turn calls Class E which does all the processing.

I am trying to start multiple threads as the processing logic and the input file is going to be same. Now my problem is, Class E has a fixed time to do the processing and if it exceeds that limit, a new thread has to be started from the Class A (main thread class) and the previous thread should be paused until the new current thread finishes.

I have tried using boolean variables by checking for the time limit in class E and then calling a function in class A that sets the `wait()` to true . See the code below

```
synchronized(this){
            while(!isRunning){
                try {
                    wait();
                    //Wrote the code to start new thread here

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(Scheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }//end of while

    }//end of synchronized

   synchronized public static void pause(){

      System.out.println("paused");
      isRunning = false;

    }//end of pause

    synchronized public static void resume(){

      System.out.println("resume");
      isRunning = true;
      notify();
    }//end of resume
```

The pause() and resume() are called from Class E. However the thread was not getting stopped and did execute and the new thread did not start after the wait().

I am must be doing a rather foundation level mistake in terms of concurrent programming ,I have tried various alternatives but in vain. I would be glad if anybody could help me out with some explanations.

Comment: This is a classic case for a series of runnable tasks and an executor.

Comment: OK, Ill take a look at using Executors, any simple example or high level explanation would help